# How to use images in theme settings

Tags: forms, media

In Drupal 7, I am trying to put an image field to allow an image to be uploaded to the [theme settings](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-add-theme-settings-drupal-7).

I am using [managed file](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) from the form API to do this. Here is my code:

```
  $form['footer']['footer_logo'] = array(
  '#title' => t('Image'),
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#description' => t('The uploaded image will be displayed on this page using the image style choosen below.'),
  '#default_value' => variable_get('footer_logo', ''),
  '#upload_location' => 'public://footer_logo/',
);
```

When I call the image using `theme_get_setting('footer_logo')`, I just get a set of numbers. How can I get the file path of the image instead? Also, is there away to pass the image through image cache settings.

Comment: Where are you using that code?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Isn't that the right code to use to allow images to be uploaded in theme settings?

Comment: I was just wondering if that code is used in a module, or in the theme-settings.php file of a theme.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I am using the code in my theme-settings file of a theme. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: @kiamlaluno I wonder, how could I upload multiple files to the theme settings?! Suppose I want to set images for a slider from the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177175/how-do-i-properly-add-file-field-in-drupal-form-via-theme-setting-php?answertab=oldest#tab-top) could provide an answer to your question :

```
$fid = theme_get_setting('footer_logo');
$image_url = file_create_url(file_load($fid)->uri);
```

(but I didn't test it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bullet proof version to get you the image URL.

Basically, it does all the checks at each function call to be 100% sure you get a proper URL and also to not throw any errors in case the image isn't uploaded or the current theme doesn't have this setting available.

When done, `$file_url` is either an empty string or a valid URL in a string.

Good luck.

```
$file_url = '';
$file_fid = theme_get_setting('footer_logo');
if(!empty($file_fid)) {
    $file_loaded = file_load($file_fid);
    if($file_loaded !== false) {
        if(!empty($file_loaded->uri)) {
            $file_url_raw = file_create_url($file_loaded->uri);
            if($file_url_raw !== false) {
                $file_url = $file_url_raw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**In addition**, the way you're saving the image files they will be set to temporary only. Check my answer here for more info on how to solve this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/136911/4861